# Rails: How to do a query to display count of unread messages if greater than 0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to display a count of unread received messages of a user. Here is part of the code from my User and Message model. So essentially, I need to do some query which will find all unread received messages of a user and then run the count function on that query. I am guessing something along these lines. Find all `received_messages` of `current_user` where `read_at IS NULL` and call the `.count` method on it. I am just not able to create the query. I am not very good with includes and joins. Can anybody help me with this??

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :received_messages, dependent: :destroy,
           :class_name => 'Message',
           :foreign_key => 'recipient_id',
           :order => "messages.created_at DESC",
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  def read?
    self.read_at.nil? ? false : true
  end
end
```

Comment: `? false : true` is unnecessary. Just `self.read_at.nil?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :unread, where(read_at: nil)
end
```

Now, you can use this [scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) to find unread messages of a user.

```
@user = User.first #or find as you want
@unread_messages = @user.received_messages.unread

#number of unread messages
@unread_messages.length
```

Note: I couldn't test these. However, this should give you some idea.